# Tabs not being recognized from RStudio text editor

Tags: text-files, rstudio

If I create a simple Makefile in an Rstudio Text File:

```
graphic1.jpeg : mouse.csv graphic1.R
  Rscript graphic1.R
```

It will not execute. I get the error message, "Makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop." because the tab in line 2 is not really a tab.

If I edit the Text File in Text Wrangler, a real tab will be inserted and the file will execute.

I have updated my RStudio Preferences / Code to ensure that the box is unchecked for "insert spaces for tab".

Is this just a bug in RStudio text editor?

Comment: What is your setting under "Tools | Project Options | Code editing | Insert spaces for Tabs"?

Comment: @user2554330 my setting there is that the box is unchecked, which I assume means I am not inserting spaces for tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just learned from an R-Bloggers post by [Jeffrey Hollister](https://www.r-bloggers.com/rstudio-and-makefiles-mind-your-options/) that there are **two** places in RStudio where I need to uncheck "Insert spaces for tab":

1) RStudio / Preferences / Code

2) Tools / Project Options / Code Editing

I am now up and running.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change this setting temporarily e.g. to tabulate a Makefile or a .tsv file, the **fastest way** is to only change the *Project Options*, do your stuff, and then revert it back.
The project options take precedence over *Global Options*, so changing the global ones only makes sense if you want to keep that option enabled for all future projects.